# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'Tag' can't be used to index type '{}'. Property 'html' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript

I have a `Meta` & `Tag` type that looks like:

```
export type Meta = {
    title: string
    date: Date
    tags: Tag[]
    slug: string // uses folder name as a slug
    lastmod?: Date
    draft?: Boolean
    description?: string
    image?: string
    authors: string[]
    readingTime: string
}

export type Tag =
    | 'html'
    | 'css'
    | 'javascript'
    | 'typescript'
    | 'localstorage'
    | 'reactjs'
    | 'next.js'
    | 'mdx'
    | 'tailwindcss'
    | 'mobx'
    | 'nodejs'
    | 'prisma'
    | 'databases'
    | 'postgresql'
    | 'sqlite'
    | 'windows'
    | 'linux'
    | 'mac'
    | 'browser-extensions'
    | 'dark-mode'
```

I have a `getTagsByPost` function that looks like:

```
const getTagsByPost = (posts: Pick<Meta, 'title' | 'slug' | 'tags'>[]) => {
    let allTags: Record<Tag, {title: string, slug: string}[]> | {} = {}
    for (let { title, slug, tags } of posts) {
        for (let tag of tags) {
            const formattedTag = tag as Tag
            const temp = { title, slug }
            if (formattedTag in allTags) {
                allTags[formattedTag].push(temp)
            } else {
                allTags[formattedTag] = [temp]
            }
        }
    }
    return allTags
}
```

I get an error on both `allTags[formattedTag]` in `if` & `else`.

The error in both `if` & `else` says:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'Tag' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> Property 'html' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(7053)

I want the function to return an object like:

```json
{
        'mobx': [{
            title: '',
            slug: ''
        }]
}
```

How do I fix it?

Reproducable TS Playground available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCywYEM4F44DeAUHKQgJYwA2wAXHAM4xTkB2A5iWQCZYx1wAIn2BdS2dg3oAVLOwDaAXTGMqAV3b0mLDnAD0euGobAGcAGYQq3YFDissAW1RYzOBus5k4VVzEcQ3AD89ML8KtxQWOYwIXAAQhBWwFisEaYAxixgMOQQrHHabF5k5I5ywIXMxSpYajAAFtBSjNUcSipQKdzF0mUCRRxEAL5ERKCQsAjIqLLseCoAPnAA5A3+VCtLqxkMDFveyysAVlgAbq5Z5DkHZEdIKAxXN9srVBAZWFRM0BW3pEculgMjBjvtXqxQDAAHRg-5wI6ObggeH3LDkKgAdzY3F24MOqwCACMURDAsA4a8wCwGOVUateNgia5TPSVpAmOwugwAI6bV68qiUYBs7GsbgQTH4u6rIWsNSkgkrcoZNlEqCSkxQAC0UOArAYeQNbN4UAA1tqAjYtkQMvkmHB2Jg5gx4ogAAoQB34AAUHJgLXd5AyZoAPBhsAAaVa5agihGrDwaFYJlYSfYAPiUAEo8BnCCoaPAvlQXfQAErAO1QbihubRggUONaNrsaNJzStHTzYZKfPLAjDPCEUbeSx2H1FwhNmjtzzR9NwIcQcxwf0MXPEbxj6BwSeYBByOArw+STcqbdkO0G+Dj8owfjcObDiRwVxwOYXy9wa8O-iOMBh0bWNZ1UDQly-S9yFXH07z4R9nzYN8qFLOQNwLb9MOQ1DJHkOCH2AJ85EUaEwGMBofX-MBs0g7ch2Ab5UC3LDLxLF08Oge8EOI4d5Co5QWNIUdv2EoTOkwNQoFYbCXRGMYnRgF03U9JgfXkLhmPEND6HkQkIBJFZoxOc5LmyGBDJjGYnjMiy3g+L4fiiJ0U0USMVBAgQVndWxDQdNB9IADTgABlGBoFQMKfHsqhQt+J0jENXR-KJILvKgXz4FirpDJUDt6HZHzyCYS19JAbUwu1d5Pm+MKnOAbVjGKEqSW1FB0qKmBtUckUuGGNzSE008Wl0lZIRAGE4SMpEUSM7AMTFXE9hc-qyA8-L4kwfg7AAYXJBIqrNMxsUaOAADkoVhBho1keacTgbbguCuAADJ0EEAKcu8PLViJTbbG1O0bG1IkDulPqNPc7S4BG4kZtWIEQUm1ZTguazrnMuBXPcygaHW4B2DYSF0sdNRyBsBAIHQQK4GOho4ErYF4AAKWCz6yG+lZfoJ1giYYbV2FJoGKth7Vae1BHzN6lbBvTHSY3RLEcTxWyJaR4zUeecyjNNC0rXjLHvDW1YAEkAJoZxWHgYRzSp8naY-BWFrgM4ACZoQABgS4p6ZSEE4BZtnSA5sowHN-VOp1kqgbFubFfFBrEvYcXfdBMHpchyQ5c5jUpX+vUDSNfZMZW8Qcc8gB1Bo+DfLoEhzrU4AAUXG-VDXtIJA7AzsVkxKvOqwLpgfrvOW4L+1blGRRsyAA).

Comment: please share reproducable example in TS playground. There are aseveral types and functions which are not declared

Comment: @captain-yossarian what is not declared? i think i've covered all. making a TS playground now :)

Comment: `IReadTimeResults`, `kebabCase`

Comment: @captain-yossarian check the recent edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{}` type denotes an empty object; it cannot have any properties of its own, but can access the properties on the global `Object`. This makes sense if you look at a literal example of an empty object:

```
const empty = {};
empty.name // doesn't exist
empty.toString() // ok
```

So `allTags` union type of `Record<...> | {}` includes an empty object which cannot be assigned any of its own properties.

A safer, compiling type here could be asserted like this instead:

```
const getTagsByPost = (posts: Pick<Meta, 'title' | 'slug' | 'tags'>[]) => {
    let allTags = {} as Record<Tag, {title: string, slug: string}[] | undefined>;
    for (let { title, slug, tags } of posts) {
        for (let tag of tags) {
            const formattedTag = tag as Tag;
            const target = allTags[formattedTag];
            const temp = { title, slug };
            if (target) {
                target.push(temp);
            } else {
                allTags[formattedTag] = [temp];
            }
        }
    }
    return allTags;
}
```

We know we will be getting an object back with `Tag` keys, but we don't have a guarantee that any particular key will be filled in. We can narrow `undefined` out of the `if` block scope by assigning the dynamic object property to a variable. See [this demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCywYEM4F44DeAsAFBzkICWMANsAFxwDOMUlAdgOakVwAmWGAzgARQcB4VsnJowAqWTgG0AupPJMaAV06MWbLnAD0RuFqbAmcAGYQafYFDjssAW1RYrOTTvVwanjCuEHwA-IxiQn58UFjWMOFwAEIQdsBY7NGWAMZsYDCUEOyJ+hzcZBSUrorAJaxlflhaMAAW0LLM9VyqflDpfGVyVcKlXKQAvqSkoJCwCMioCpx4fgA+cADkLUE0G2ub2UxMexXk6xsAVlgAbp65lPknvOdIKEz3j-sbNBDZWDQsaA1J4Uc59LDZGAXY5fdigGAAOmhILOm1cfBAKLgLywlBoAHcOHxDjDTti0RAAEaY2EhYDIr5gNhMapY84CbCUzyWNmbSAsTh9JgAR12XxFNGowF5G0J7D4EHxpOem0l7C0NLJ52q2RllKgiosUAAtPDgOwmIULTKBFAANbG4IOE6kbJFFhwTiYJZMJKIAAKEA9+AAFPyYB1-ZRsnaADwYbAAGk2BVo0vJGx8nA2GekxwAfKoAJR4fOEPx0eD-Gg+vCEcZwTxwABKwDdUD4saWyYIqboei6nGTWYHBk441U+YA3H5bE4Q5XCFQ08PtEOEIorA2INY4OGmCXiGTeHO4AvMBvljvLwfy8feBQ3Rb4HPqjAhHwlnXpI2rEsZ-eD5wE+HrYFAXrwPg1Y+kor6CB+SwqABQFASB8BCK4YB1gQy50KuOhwOMyEobwlC7iGYEQYefgkbwlGYAiYDmC0FHAJhRbEbRhFwMAAKoEeXFAdBm6wdAb4IYoKh1koGFgEhNEoZMgGEX4Sm8H0MBaFA7CNjQNabgBSmkCYcByAsADKHzoS0HB2lYrSUFYjnMHEqCUs0cDUHAhJ6QgLQGvijY6Y4BpOGRcBQFomQkK67roZYkFwEoAlSNQ-ZwAARH2wAZYmfgjplWa5X4eaMEoGXbK4NAZb+wFxWoJDjPJMUkGhEWWFoNCJRBPp+oGLCsSwHFTCQQqdYiHJYFyFhMAic4AKIQixfClnVFppAiPycCGfAItlRYcUAA) for an explanation as to why an `undefined` type is required.

Comment: Is there a reason to add `undefined` in there? It works fine without it :)

Comment: As explained at the end, there's no guarantee that any particular key will be added to the object, because there's no guarantee that they are all present in the data provided by `posts`. When you try to access a non-existent property on an object, the result is `undefined`.

Comment: But adding `undefined` gives error for weird reason. I think my `if` check is on point if something doesn't exist :)

Comment: @deadcoder0904 see the edit for a fix for the `if` issue, and a demo showing why it is unsafe to leave out the `undefined` type.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation & the demo. I marked your answer as the correct one as it saves runtime error haha. I forgot typescript only spots the build-time error. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const getTagsByPost = (posts: Pick<Meta, 'title' | 'slug' | 'tags'>[]) => {
    let allTags: Record<Tag, {title: string, slug: string}[]> = {} as Record<Tag, {title: string, slug: string}[]>
    for (let { title, slug, tags } of posts) {
        for (let tag of tags) {
            const formattedTag = kebabCase(tag) as Tag
            const temp = { title, slug }
            if (formattedTag in allTags) {
                allTags[formattedTag].push(temp)
            } else {
                allTags[formattedTag] = [temp]
            }
        }
    }
    return allTags
}
```

The object literal syntax `{}` refer to the type 'object'.

When you declare `allTags` variable with union type that include `{}` and initialize it with an object literal, `allTags` variable now is type of `object` so it can't not have a key of type `Tag` when you write `allTags[formattedTag]`.

And if you want initialize an empty object with the type of `Record<Tag, {title: string, slug: string}[]>`, use the keyword `as` to cast will do the trick.

Comment: This fixes it. Can you add why it fixes?